# How to tell how often a Lambda is reused?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I know one shouldn't rely on a Lambda being reused, and that's not my goal. Just trying to get an idea of how many invocations I'm getting handled by the same instance of a Lambda.

Looking at the graphs below, it shows that at some point in time, there were 5,093 invocations and 57 concurrent executions at that same point in time.

## Question

Can I assume all of those invocations were handled by those concurrent executions? Thus, 5093 / 57 = ~89 requests handled by each lambda instance on average?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Yes, I think so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [Lambda docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-metrics.html#monitoring-metrics-types):

> `Invocations` – The number of times your function code is executed, including successful executions and executions that result in a function error. Invocations aren't recorded if the invocation request is throttled or otherwise resulted in an invocation error. This equals the number of requests billed.

and

> `ConcurrentExecutions` – The number of function instances that are processing events. If this number reaches your concurrent executions quota for the Region, or the reserved concurrency limit that you configured on the function, additional invocation requests are throttled.

Based on this I think your interpretation is correct, you can divide `Invocations` by `ConcurrentExecutions` to get the number of requests each execution context (instance) has handled on average. Note that there might be a lot of variance in the numbers, which you can't measure based on the available metrics. You'd have to generate your own metrics for that.